# Freezer ice maker not working - tech and I are stumped, Frigidaire FGHS2631PF4A

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker, freezer

My ice maker stopped making ice, and I had a tech come out, but he couldn't find the root cause.
We checked that the temperature in the freezer was fine. The ice maker arms would cycle when triggered manually. The heating element is heating up. There's appropriate water pressure. There's nothing blocking the water line (like ice).
I thought the water inlet valve had failed, but after I had the door open for a while and manually cycled the ice maker, it actually filled with water. That might suggest that there was freezing in the line, but that's not possible in this case since the water line is outside the freezer in this model.
We're thinking that maybe it's the control board, but we can't find any other symptoms that would suggest a control board malfunction.

For several months before it failed, I noticed it was making a very bizarre sound. I did some research into refrigerator noises, but I can't find any description of a matching sound. I noticed it happening maybe once every few hours.

Here is an audio clip: https://sndup.net/wj6b/

My refrigerator is a Frigidaire Gallery model FGHS2631PF4A.

Comment: `but we can't find any other symptoms that would suggest a control board malfunction.` why should there be more than one symptom?

Comment: @jsotola How could I confirm that it's not the water inlet valve?

Comment: you said that the tray filled with water

Comment: IDK if the Frigidaires are the same, but my Samsung/GE icemaker has plastic gears inside that strip.  Any chance yours are similar?  In my case replacing the entire icemaker—about $100—solved the problem.